# Disable touch animation in UIButton in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uilabel, selection

I want to disable the animation of button is touch down or selection. I want to mimic the feature that selection is happening on label. I am comfortable with the properties of button compare to uilabel because i can give my background image and it also help me in more issues.

Please help me in this?

Answer (score 6):

I think what you need is to unselect the "Highlighted adjusts image" option in Interface Builder:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

2018 people, Swift 4.0:

Setting the button's `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` property worked. Need this in my custom `UITabBarController` (e.g. large center tabBarItem).

Answer (score 0):

Disable the user interaction of your button.

```
myButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score -2):

set your button type as custom.

```
myButton.buttonType = UIButtonTypeCustom;
```